# CMake error on Windows when building extra modules and CUDA

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am using Windows and using the CMake GUI. In CMake, I set the source code path at

```
C:/Users/me/Downloads/opencv
```

`opencv` and `opencv_contrib`were obtained from the OpenCV github repos

I set the build path in Cmake as `C:/Users/me/Downloads/builds/opencv`

I then set `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` as `C:/Users/me/Downloads/opencv-3.4/source/opencv_contrib/modules` and checked `WITH_CUDA`

after Configuring, I get the error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake:125 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake:174 (ocv_wipeout_deprecated)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:43 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:688 (include)
```

can anyone help with this?

Comment: What version/flavor of Cuda are you using?

Comment: I'm using 10.2 in windows

Comment: Can you try to build extra modules and CUDA seperately to see which one really causing the error?

Comment: if I try `configure` without selecting `WITH_CUDA`, I get the error `duplicated modules LOCATION has been found`. How would I build CUDA separately without extra modules?

Comment: actually when I `configure`d without selecting `WITH_CUDA`, I forgot to delete the cache. After I deleted it and reconfigured it, the extra modules was able to `configure` and `generate` successfully